# Conditional Formatting Referencing another Cell (and using addition)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am tracking high school credit acquisition. Each trimester a student must earn 2 credits to remain on track. If Cell A1 is "trimester 1 total credits", and cell B1 is "trimester 2 total credits", I need a formula to the effect of "B1>=A1+2 then turn GREEN".

Answer (score 1):

In the formatting dialog, select "custom formula" with the formula `= B1>=A1+2`.
That is, enter the inequality or equality you wish to trigger the formatting, preceded by `=` sign.

[image: custom formula]